# Retaining information through recursion under strict conditions (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, recursion

My partner and I are working on a problem in which we need to reduce an array and run operations on the pieces (in this case, of 2), we are reducing with recursion and sending the left-right hand sides of the array back into function.

We have all this working fine, and for example, using the array [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] we get all the pieces we need.

The problem is, we need each of these pieces to then run the math operation on the next piece we get.

So, for example we recur down to [2, 3] and transform that into [5, -1]. Then we recur down to [4, 5] and change that into [9, -1] and combine them into [14, -2, -4, 0]. This is the left hand side of our array. And this works great. And then it does the right hand side, and it gets the answer we want. This works great.

The problem, is we now need both parts together (can't use global variables). And we have been stuck here for several hours. We can only pass the simplified array through the recursion, and if we initialize an array to hold both parts it will get reset when the right-hand side starts.

Thanks

EDIT: Code: The H is starting matrix that is given, but it doesn't matter, it as no relevance its just there so the unit test goes through (We could use it, but we don't really know how)

The imput for x is [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

```
def hadmatmult(H, x):

 d = 0
 n = len(x)
first = 0
last = len(x)
a = [0] * math.floor(n/2)
b = [0] * math.floor(n/2)
if n == 2:
  temp1 = x[0]
  x[0] = temp1 + x[1]
  x[1] = temp1 - x[1]
else:
  mid = math.floor((first+last)/2)
  for i in range(first, mid):
    a[i] = x[i]
  hadmatmult(H, a)

  for j in range(mid, last):
    b[d] = x[j]
    d = d + 1
  hadmatmult(H, b)
  if(len(a) == 2:
    adds = [0] * len(a)
    subs = [0] * len(a)
    for t in range(0, len(a)):
      adds[t] = a[t] + b[t]
      subs[t] = a[t] - b[t]
    #alladds = alladds + adds
    #allsubs = allsubs + subs
    print(adds)
    print(subs)
```

Output: This outputs the parts, [14, -2, -4, 0] and [30, -2, -4, 0]

Comment: I think classically you'd pass an index and recursion level and use that to directly access the correct items in the array.

Comment: Please include your code and current results in your question

Comment: Would you be able to explain this further? An example output would also be useful. Also, current code (in a minimal fashion) would help too.

Comment: It will help a lot of people if you'd explain that you're doing the sum and difference of numbers in pairs -- and walk through an example.  Otherwise, the output you have isn't particularly distinctive, given the powers of 2 and zeroes in the rest of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must recurse, do so in a simpler way. Strip off the elements you need and recurse through the rest.

```
x = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

def recurse_and_stuff(x):
    if len(x) == 0:
        # base case
        return []
    a, b, = x[:2], x[2:4]
    m,n,o,p = [a[0]+a[1], a[0]-a[1], b[0]+b[1], b[0]-b[1]]
    result = [[m+o, n+p, m-o, n-p]] + recurse_and_stuff(x[4:])
    return result

>>> x = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> recurse_and_stuff(x)
[[14, -2, -4, 0], [30, -2, -4, 0]]
>>> x = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
>>> recurse_and_stuff(x)
[[14, -2, -4, 0], [30, -2, -4, 0], [46, -2, -4, 0], [62, -2, -4, 0]]
# works for longer inputs as long as len(x) % 4 == 0
```

To recurse all the way down:

```
import itertools

def do_the_needful(a,b):
    try:
        zipped = zip(a,b)
    except TypeError:
        # a and b are ints, not lists of ints
        zipped = [(a,b)]
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(*[[aa+bb, aa-bb] for aa,bb in zipped]))


def recurse_and_stuff(x):
    if len(x) == 1:
        return list(x[0])
        # if you only have to iterate through this, there's no
        # need to call `list(...)` here.
    return recurse_and_stuff([do_the_needful(x[i], x[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(x), 2)])
```

Comment: Wow, that code is a lot cleaner than ours. However, it doesn't give a different output. You were right in your first post, we need to foil those final two answers. I haven't had time to run tests on your code, but it gets those two sets on two separate recursions. Meaning we are back at our problem of not being able to compare/ "foil" them.

Comment: Then you're really not making yourself very clear.... What's your EXPECTED OUTPUT? You said it was `[14, -2, -4, 0], [30, -2, -4, 0]` which is what this code does...

Comment: [44, -4, -8, 0, -16, 0, 0, 0] Sorry, by your other post I thought you knew about that final step. We have a bunch of paper with the tree, and it just seems like there is this wall in the middle that we can't cross. We have been trying to use the H and pass information but that isn't as easy as we thought.

Comment: The problem is that your first step `[2,3] -> [5, -1]` is different from the rest of your steps `[5, -1, 9, -1] -> [14, -2, -4, 0]` so it's difficult to tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: WAIT NO, I'm thinking too shallow. I've got it. Editing shortly.

Comment: Yeah they are, the full question is a hadamard matrix multiplied by an array. So the first thing you have to do is compared your groups of two to the base case of hadamard. Which leads to the 2+3 2-3. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I'm awful with the math. I've got the algorithm in my head now though, let me write it down and test it

Comment: @BNSlug okay, edited. I used a helper function to actually do the needful (and hide the ugly `list(itertools.chain(zip(*[[...] ... ])))` crud, but you could certainly unroll it

Comment: Works like a charm, and I see what you did. I have never used itertools though, is the try/except part of needful needed for the functionality, or is that part of the tool?

Comment: @BNSlug It's special-casing the outermost recursion, which will send `int, int` instead of `[int...], [int...]`. The line that does work expects the latter, so we build it into that shape before processing.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I can see how to apply that.